# What is the ideal way to make a unique list of values in C?

Tags: c

Say we have

```
typedef struct {
  int value1;
  int value2;
} values_t;
```

and

```
values_t* values;
```

is filled with *values[i].value1* and *values[i].value2* pairs that may or may not be unique.

and we want to fill

```
values_t* values_unique;
```

only with *unique* pairs from *values*, in the order they first appear in *values*.

What is the ideal way to do this in C?

EDIT: Assume they are properly malloced pointers; above is just pseudo code.

Comment: `values_t values` is not an array.

Comment: `values[i].value1` would be a compile error. Can you post the actual code you have?

Comment: Yeah sorry, assume they are properly malloced pointers; above is just pseudo code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably use a hash of the values, maintaining a list of the hashes and the corresponding values, and only add a new pair to the `values_unique` array (which the question <s>does</s> originally did not declare as an array) if it is not found via the hash.  If the list is large, the speed up from hashing instead of searching through the entire list sequentially can be quite significant.

Comment: Yeah sorry, assume they are properly malloced pointers; above is just pseudo code.

Comment: If your hash implementation is very simple, each time you append a value `v` to the new list, you can add to your hash table a mapping from `h(v)` to the index position of the tuple you've added.  Then when checking if `v2` is already in the list, find `h(v2)` in the hash and use the index position to find the `v`, which you can then compare with `v2` to determine if they are identical.

Answer (score 1):

It'll be something like this (Haven't been coding in C for long time, and code isn't tested):

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct {
  int value1;
  int value2;
} values_t;
values_t* values;
size_t values_size = 100;
values_t* values_unique;
size_t values_unique_size;
int valcmp(const values_t* a, const values_t* b)
{
    //a < b -> -1
    //a == b -> 0
    //a > b -> 1
    return (a->value1 == b->value1) ? ((a->value2 == b->value2) ? 0 : ((a->value2 < b->value2) ? -1 : 1)) : ((a->value1 < b->value1) ? -1 : 1);
}
int main(void)
{
    values = malloc(values_size * sizeof(values_t));
    values_unique = malloc(values_size * sizeof(values_t));
    //fill the values table
    memcpy(values_unique, values, values_size * sizeof(values_t));
    qsort(values_unique, values_size, sizeof(values_t), valcmp);
    int i;
    //hopefully values_size > 0
    for(i = 1, values_unique_size = 1; i < values_size; ++i)
        if(valcmp(&values_unique[i], &values_unique[values_unique_size - 1]) != 0)
            values_unique[values_unique_size] = values_unique[i];
}
```

Same in c++:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<pair<int,int> > V, V_unique;

int main()
{
    V_unique = V;
    sort(V_unique.begin(), V_unique.end());
    V_unique.resize(unique(V_unique.begin(), V_unique.end()) - V_unique.begin());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's fairly annoying to suggest a different language but using C++ stl would be trivial.

```
set<values_t> mySet();

for(int i=0; i < number_of_values; i++)
{
    mySet.insert(values[i]);
}

values_t * values_unique = new values_t[mySet.size()];

int j=0;

for(set<values_t>::iterator i = mySet.begin(); mySet.end() != i; i++)
{
    values_unique[j] = *i;
    j++
}
```

Comment: This is missing a comparator / `operator<` for `values_t`. Also, why not use just use sets input iterator based constructor and `std::copy()` instead of manual insertion/copying?